# Fabric JS gradient color

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js and needs to make gradient color.

Fabric JS Fiddle 
[Fabric link](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhatt/e425a3ew/)

Reference canvas gradient
[Reference Gredient link](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhatt/7x4q91kj/)

Please guide me for the Fabric js to achieve the gradient like using normal canvas.

```
Fabric JS :+Snap of code 
rect.setGradient('fill', {
  x1: 0,
  y1: -rect.height,
  x2: rect.width,
  y2: rect.height,
  colorStops: {
    0: "black",
    0.5: "red",
    1: "blue"
  }
});

Normal Canvas Code :
var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(45,50,170,90);
grd.addColorStop(0,"black");
grd.addColorStop(0.5,"red");
grd.addColorStop(1,"blue");
ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
```

Comment: make jsfiddle and working demo in live and let us know with that example link

Comment: I already shared here check it sharing again    
Fabric JS : http://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhatt/e425a3ew/  

Reference  : http://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhatt/7x4q91kj/

Comment: You are going with perfect way, what is problem than?

Comment: i want to make gradient box from gradient generator and same values put into fabric object so user can make his own gradient, but i am not getting proper Values of X1 Y1 X2 Y2  in fabric js as generator has made check the fiddle for the same FABRIC JS : http://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhatt/e425a3ew/2/   , CANVAS GENERATOR http://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhatt/7x4q91kj/

Comment: Please guide me if any one knows how to set the X1 Y1 X2 Y2

Comment: Can we use setGradient in image object using fabric ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to achieve gradient using fabricjs with 3 colors. You can do this something like this using fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/keyur12/ez5vbef4/1/).

```
//diagonal
rect.setGradient('fill', {
    x1: -rect.width / 2,
    y1: -rect.height / 2,
    x2: rect.width / 2,
    y2: rect.height / 2,
    colorStops: {
    0: "black",
    0.5: "red",
    1: "blue"
    }
    });  
// horizontal
    rect.setGradient('fill', {
     x1: -rect.width / 2,
     y1: 0,
     x2: rect.width / 2,
     y2: 0,
     colorStops: {
       0: "black",
       0.5: "red",
       1: "blue"
     }
    });

    // vertical just change below
     x1: 0,
     y1: -rect.height / 2,
     x2: 0,
     y2: rect.height / 2,
```

[image]
[image]